# Sharemouse not working after switch to USB wireless mouse

Tags: mouse

I recently changed from a wired [Logitech Trackman Wheel](https://support.logitech.com/n_us/product/trackman-wheel) to a wireless [Logitech M570 Trackball](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-trackball-m570) (which has a USB receiver plugged into the USB port on an [Apple wired keyboard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa)) that is physically plugged into an early 2009 Mac Pro. I use [Sharemouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/) v2.0.53 to virtually share the mouse and keyboard between the Pro and a 2012 Mac mini.

Since changing mice, the mouse's scroll wheel no longer works on the "remote" mini (neither do the new thumb buttons, but I can live without those). Everything else with the keyboard and mouse still works. I tried installing the Logitech Control Center software on the mini, but since the USB receiver isn't actually plugged into that computer, it doesn't even recognize that a Logitech mouse is "attached" to it.

I tried plugging the USB receiver directly into a USB port on the computer, instead of into the keyboard, but that didn't make any difference. Any ideas? Or alternatives to Sharemouse? (My "free maintenance" time is up and I would have to purchase another license to get an updated version, and I don't like that they want $50 instead of $20 just because I have three monitors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of tools to modify the scroll wheel's behavior, such as Karabiner and BetterTouchTool, with no change, I realized that the way Sharemouse controls the "remote" computer (mini) is through Accessibility, and so probably doesn't fire the normal events for those applications to catch and modify, therefore I'd probably need to adjust the events that were actually firing on the host computer before Sharemouse intercepted them and passed them to the remote computer. I did, however, figure out that the scroll wheel is working - it's just scrolling horizontally instead of vertically. (It's a two-way wheel that does not tilt side-to-side, so it should always be scrolling vertically.)

I then tried installed Karabiner on the host Mac Pro and created a custom bit that got the scroll wheel going vertically on the mini, but it was like scrolling through molasses. Figuring I had nothing to lose, I tried uninstalling the Logitech Control Center software and after rebooting, scrolling was back to horizontal on the mini. I turned off the Karabiner setting I had created, and scrolling now correctly works vertically...except the thumb buttons do nothing, since LCC was handling the functions of those buttons. I'll have to play with Karabiner and see what I can get them to do, but at least scrolling works on the mini again.